# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable?

Tags: python, text, types

Hi i got a problem i dont understand why i got a Type error please explain what it is and how i can fix it
Thanks in advance!

```
abb = raw_input("Abbreviation: ")
text = raw_input("Text: ")
text = text.lower().split()
abb = abb.lower().split
list1 = []
i = 0
j = 0

while i < len(text):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].startswith(abb[0]):
            list1.append(text[i])
            for i in range(len(text)):
                if text[i].startswith(abb[1]):
                    list1.append(text[i])
                    for i in range(len(text)):
                        if text[i].startswith(abb[2]):
                            list1.append(text[i])
```

Comment: does this have to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298698/need-to-create-a-program-that-prints-out-words-starting-with-a-particular-letter , homework?

Answer (score 6):

Check out your line

```
abb = abb.lower().split
```

(and compare it the correct line above it). You don't call the function, you just assign `abb` to the same object as the method `split` itself.

Hence when you try `abb[0]`, it tries to subscript the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Change `abb = abb.lower().split` to `abb = abb.lower().split()`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that at some point in your code where you are using square bracket notation (which is 'subscripting' an iterable) the thing is not iterable. Somewhere where you think you have a string you actually have a function.

That is what the error message is telling you anyway. When you debug a bit of code like this just drop lots of print statements in and see where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On line 4, you put

```
abb = abb.lower().split
```

That would give you the split function of the lowercase abb string instead of calling it. Simply change the code above to:

```
abb = abb.lower().split()
```

Just like you did with your code in the previous line with the string text.